# JavaScript classList not working while clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently creating a dropdown menu so I want the menu to be displayed when clicked by adding class via Javascript but classList is not working at all. I tried lots of time but couldn't. Also if i add `style.display = "block"`, then it works! I am unable to figure out! Please Help me!

```js
document.getElementById('dbtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('d-content').classList.toggle('show');
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#dbtn {
  background-color: #F44336;
  font-size: 27px;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  border: none;
  padding: 0.3em 0.6em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

#d-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  background-color: #F44336;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  border-top: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#d-content a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.3em 5em 0.3em 0.3em;
}

#d-content a:hover {
  background-color: darkorchid;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Dropdown Menu</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <input type="button" id="dbtn" value="Select..." />
    <div id="d-content" class="drop">
      <a>USA</a>
      <a>Canada</a>
      <a>Europe</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser calculates css properties based on selectors order and selectors weight. In your case `#id` selector overrides your class selector.

```
.show {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Or it's better not to use important at all:

```
#d-content.show{
    display: block ;
}
```

You can read more about selectors weight [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Also you can alaways check those kind of things in [dev console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/). [image]

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot Bro! Will tick answer in 9 Minutes!

Comment: Thanks! I prefer second answer!

Comment: Aaah! Thanks for that! That's gonna help much!

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, the **id** selector has far more weight over the **class** selector.

You need to add `!important;` to your `.show` `display` rule.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using the wrong approach (Don't worry it happens, and it's okay). it would be easier if you just toggle the display property it will save lot of your time. you can toggle the display property using following snippest:

```
document.getElementById('dbtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var dContent = document.getElementById('d-content');
        dContent.style.display = dContent.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';

    });
```

Comment: classList.toggle does all. There's no need of custom toggling! But I liked your answer.

Comment: thanks bill. What i'm trying to say here is it will save you from creating special class for show in stylesheet.

Comment: Yeah! I appreciate it!